# Select dynamically added li in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending li in a Ul dynamically with a rel attribute. Now I need to select the last li and it's attributes. But it is unable to select the dynamically added li.

```
  var lastRel = $("#ulid li:last").attr("rel");


$("#addLi").on('click', function(){
$("ul").append('<li rel="5">5</li>');
});


$("#getLast").on('click', function(){
alert(lastRel);
});
```

Check this Fiddle..

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oum8e687/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the code where you get the last reference of `li` in the button click:

```
$("#getLast").on('click', function(){
    var lastRel = $("#ulid li:last").attr("rel");
    alert(lastRel);
});
```

This is because when you originally set your variable, it is at page load when there are only 4 `li`'s.

You need to set the variable again when you have updated the last `li`.

```js
$("#addLi").on('click', function(){
  let liLength = $("li").length + 1;
  $("ul").append('<li rel="'+liLength+'">'+liLength+'</li>');
});


$("#getLast").on('click', function(){
  var lastRel = $("#ulid li:last").attr("rel");
  alert(lastRel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulid">
  <li rel="1">1</li>
  <li rel="2">2</li>
  <li rel="3">3</li>
  <li rel="4">4</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="addLi" name="addLi" value="Add Li">

<input type="button" id="getLast" name="getLast" value="Read Last LI">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `lastRel` after adding a new `<li>`

```
$("#addLi").on('click', function(){
    $("ul").append('<li rel="5">5</li>');
    lastRel = $("#ulid li:last").attr("rel");
});

$("#getLast").on('click', function(){
    alert(lastRel);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oum8e687/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have done was right you have misplaced this code

```
var lastRel = $("#ulid li:last").attr("rel");
```

This piece of code should come inside your click event.

But i suggest you to have Id dynamically for the li also. So you can directly access the selector.

Example:

```
<li id="name-1"></li>
<li id="name-2"></li>
```

So in my jQuery I can do something like this

```
$("#name-"+id).val();
```